# Converted lead results in 'ConvertedAccountId' being NULL?

Tags: rest-api, lead-conversion

I am responsible for an integration with our customer's Salesforce systems using the REST API.  I have been operating under the assumption that whenever a `Lead` is converted, then it will have the field `ConvertedAccountId` equal to the ID of the `Account` that it was converted into, and optionally the field `ConvertedOpportunityId` would not be NULL if they also chose to create an opportunity at the time of the conversion.

Most of the time this assumption holds, however, I have run across some Leads that have been converted (denoted by the field `IsConverted = True`)  but the field `ConvertedAccountId = NULL`.  It is often the case that the fields `ConvertedOpportunityId` and `ConvertedContactId` are `NULL` as well.

My question is:  under what conditions would `Lead.IsConverted == True` but not have an associated `ConvertedAccountId`.  I had a guess that perhaps it was because the `Account` that it was originally converted into was subsequently deleted, but I tested that scenario and it does not hold.

All guesses are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you are not explicitly setting `isConvert=true;` ?

Comment: how exactly are leads being converted? by the user using the OOB Lead Convert button? By a custom VF button? something else?  The OOB SFDC REST API doesn't support lead conversion.

Comment: Great questions.  I'm not sure that I would be able to tell how the leads are being converted as I only have access to the REST API to access the data.  Is it allowed for someone to explicitly set `IsConverted = TRUE` without actually doing a conversion?